# Are "would" and "used to" the same when describing repetitive actions?

Tags: past-tense, verb-forms, clauses

What is the correct form of the following two sentences?

> Tom *used to live*/*would* live in the house at the end of the street.

(I think that both answers are possible, because they both mean Tom lived in the house at the end of the street but now he doesn't live there any more).

> She *would/used to be* a doctor.

(Here probably could be 'She used to be a doctor', I'm not sure if the first form with *would* is correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Used to* is correct in both cases, and *would* is incorrect.

*Would* in this sense is used for repeated action in the past, not continuous action. "We would go to the corner store after school" is fine (*used to* also works here). "Tom would live in the house at the end of the street" is not.

Comment: BTW, will the sentence have the same meaning if we replace _used to_ with _get used to_?

Comment: no the meaning won't be the same

Comment: @DmitryFucintv *Get used to* means *Become accustomed to*.